# MySql Sum different types of expenses from 'expense' table based on value in 'expense type' group by employee

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

A more generic title for this post would be

> MySql Sum different columns in same table based on value of another row, group by yet another row

I have a table of employee expenses:

```
id | employee_id | expense_cat_id | expense_amount |
 1  | 11          | 1              | 100            |
 2  | 11          | 1              | 200            |
 3  | 12          | 1              | 120            |
 4  | 12          | 1              | 140            |
 5  | 11          | 2              | 5              |
 6  | 12          | 2              | 8              |`
```

and I want to produce a report like this:

`Employee Id | Expense Cat 1 Total Amount | Expense Cat 2 Total Amount
11           | 300                        | 5
12           | 260                        | 8`

So initially I thought I could use 2 table aliases for the same table like this:

`SELECT
  employee_id,
  sum(expense_cat_1.expense_amount) as expense_1_total,
  sum(expense_cat_2.expense_amount) as expense_2_total
FROM
  expenses as expense_cat_1 where expense_cat_1.expense_cat_id=1 , 
  expenses as expense_cat_2 where expense_cat_2.expense_cat_id=2
group by employee_id`

but this was not correct Sql Syntax, which makes sense to me.

So I thought I could do two joins on between employee table and the expenses table:

`SELECT
employees.id as employee_id,
sum(expenses_cat_1.expense_amount) as expense_1_total,
sum(expenses_cat_2.expense_amount) as expense_2_total
FROM employees
join expenses as expenses_cat_1 on employees.id = expenses_cat_1.employee_id and expenses_cat_1.expense_cat_id=1 
join expenses as expenses_cat_2 on employees.id = expenses_cat_2.employee_id and expenses_cat_2.expense_cat_id=2
group by employees.id`

Which comes close, but is wrong:

`employee_id | expense_1_total | expense_2_total
11          | 300             | 10
12          | 260             | 16`

as the expense 2 total is doubled! I think this is because the join on shows up two rows for each of the two expenses with category 1, and sums them.

I also tried a sub-query approach:

`SELECT (SELECT sum(expense_amount)
 FROM expenses 
 WHERE expense_cat_id = 1) AS sum1 ,
 (SELECT sum(expense_amount)
 FROM expenses
 WHERE expense_cat_id = 2) AS sum2,
 employee_id
 FROM expenses group by employee_id`

but this has the same problem as the join approach - totals for cat 2 are doubled.

How do I make the second join only include the expense_2_total once ???

I have a personal dislike of sql case statements as they seem more of a procedural language construct (and sql is declarative), but am happy to consider their use in this case - but I put the challenge out there for sql experts to solve this elegantly.

Comment: What if there's more than two cats? Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT employee_id,
       sum(case when expense_cat_id = 1 then expense_amount else 0 end) as expense_1_total,
       sum(case when expense_cat_id = 2 then expense_amount else 0 end) as expense_2_total
FROM expenses e
GROUP BY employee_id;
```